# How to double-check a LUKS passphrase

Tags: password, luks, cryptsetup

This is a way I enter a new passphrase for my encrypted volume:

```bash
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey --key-slot 4  /dev/sda5
```

Unfortunately, `cryptsetup` does not ask to confirm the new passphrase. How to make sure that the passphrase I have entered is the one that I actually meant?

I see two workarounds.

1. Reboot and try the new passphrase.
2. Add a temporary passphrase to another slot with the help of the new passphrase. Kill the temporary passphrase.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: `--verify-passphrase`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run `cryptsetup` with argument `-y`.

From the manpage of `cryptsetup`:

```
--verify-passphrase, -y
    query for passwords twice. Useful when creating a (regular) mapping for the first time, 
    or when running luksFormat.
```

The system would ask twice for an existing passphrase and for a new one:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey -y --key-slot 4  /dev/sda5
Enter any existing passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
Enter new passphrase for key slot: 
Verify passphrase: 
Passphrases do not match.
```